# PHP MongoDB findone $and

Tags: php, mongodb, find

How would I find a row with two objects? Example:

```
    $m = new Mongo();
    $db = $m->mydb->user_tokens;
    $cursor = $db->findOne(array('$and' => array('user_id' => $userid, 'token_id' => $tokenid)));
```

I'm not sure if you can even do this in PHP. I have a python backend server that I can do something similar to this but need to be able to do it on the frontend as well.

Comment: Please make a better question title than a dump of keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the $and qualifier; just setting your two conditions should work fine.

In php one thing I've found useful is to take your query; then do a:

```
echo(json_encode($query));
```

This way you can take your query and try it directly on the console to confirm it's showing what you're thinking it should.

A bit further into the above explained..
Currently this is what you're querying on:

```
{"$and":{"user_id":"userId","token_id":"tokenId"}}
```

I found this out by doing

```
echo(json_encode(array('$and' => array('user_id' => 'userId', 'token_id' => 'tokenId'))));
```

You want to be doing either:

```
{"$and":[{"user_id":"userId"},{"token_id":"tokenId"}]}

or

{"user_id":"userId","token_id":"tokenId"}
```

Useful sheet to look up when creating your queries:

> [SQL to Mongo Cheat Sheet](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart)

Comment: NOTE: if you wehre doing something like a GTE on the second operator you would then want to use and and you need an extra array() around your userid, tokenid to create the array look. See Here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24and

Comment: I have read the DOCS and cheat sheet but really doesn't explain for it in PHP. When I use both conditions if there is 2 documents with one of the same conditions than it shows all the results with the same condition. I have tried `$cursor = $db->findOne(array('$and' => array('user_id' => $userid), array('token_id' => $tokenid)));` But that makes the page than wont load..

Comment: `{"$and":[{"user_id":"userId"},{"token_id":"tokenId"}]}` would work for javascript, not PHP. @Frederico

Comment: @Bobby correct; that is what the console uses, you create your php through the use of those array's then you can json_encode it to confirm you have the correct code.  I was using it as an example.